# what are the limitations of Microsoft flow as compare to designer workflow.

Tags: microsoft-flow

I have created few Microsoft flow using templates.

I would like to know the limitations of Microsoft flow.

Just like in Designer workflow We are able to break item level permission and assign new one.

Like above scenario is possible in Microsoft flow.

Also please mentions  other limitations also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good day,

As far as I know breaking the item level permission in Flow and assigning a new one is not possible. In the SharePoint action - Update Item there is no option to change the privileges of the list item which you are editing.

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible to manage SharePoint permissions in Microsoft Flow with the help of [Plumsail SharePoint](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/actions/sharepoint-processing.html) (Third-party connector), which is a part of [Plumsail Actions](https://plumsail.com/actions/) product with a fair price.

There is an action, called [Change Permissions](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/actions/sharepoint-processing.html#change-permissions-on-site-list-or-list-item) that gives you the ability to:

- Grant Permissions on Site
- Remove Permissions from Site
- Remove All Permissions from Site
- Restore Permissions Inheritance for Site
- Grant Permissions on List
- Remove Permissions from List
- Remove All Permissions from List
- Restore Permissions Inheritance for List
- Grant Permissions on Item
- Remove Permissions from Item
- Remove All Permissions from Item
- Restore Permissions Inheritance for Item

Here are a couple of examples of Flows:

[Set item level permissions (break role inheritance and assign permissions)](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/set-item-level-permissions.html)

[Create site by custom template and grant permissions](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-site-by-custom-template-and-grant-permissions.html)

Regarding the limitations of Microsoft Flow. SharePoint Designer functionality is almost covered in Microsoft Flow. There are still some issues with reading and writing multichoice fields, lookups, and metadata columns. But Microsoft team claims to fix it soon.

SharePoint Designer workflows can be started under App step permissions. Microsoft Flow is always started by a user who specified credentials in SharePoint connector.

SharePoint Designer workflow can be edited by any user with appropriate permissions on a SharePoint site. Microsoft Flow has Team Flows instead. That allows a few users to collaborate on the same Flow.

**Note:** I'm a part of Plumsail Actions development team

Comment: This answer seems to be missing the requested limitations of flow.

Comment: @Nullldata, I updated the answer to reflect limitation (differences) as well.

Comment: Thanks @Anton Khritonenkov :) It's actually quite difficult to track down the known limitations of flow, due to the sheer amount of web pages on the subject. Eagerly awaiting some SharePoint designer workflow abilities to appear in flow :) One such limitation I have encountered is the ability to work with the "Approval Status" field.